# Auto-Pagebreaks that respect Enumerate environments

Tags: page-breaking

I want my document to auto pagebreak whenever an enumerate environment will fail to fit at the bottom of the page. Is there any way to do this besides with minipages around each enumerate environment?

Comment: You don't need minipages  around an enumerate environment!

Comment: I know I don't *need* them always, but if I want to guarantee that the enumerate environment will not be split between two pages, this would work, yes?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to have if the enumerate is too long to fit on the page. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: If the enumerate will not fit at the end of a page, it should fall onto the next page.

The doc I am trying to create is like an exam where there are many enumerate envs, each being a set of possible answers, inside one large enumerate env where each item is a question. I want to make sure that each question-answers set appears on a single page.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to make the upper-level enumerate  a customised (sub)section? The `titlesec` package has tools for such a behaviour

Comment: That seems more complicated. I am not incredible skilled with LaTeX...

Comment: It seems like a reasonable solution is to make a new environment and do something like this:

\newenvironment{questionanswer}
{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} \item}
{\end{minipage}}

I can then replace all of the \items in the upper enumerate with \begin{quesitonanswer} and follow the inner enumerate with an \end{questionanswer}

Comment: The thing to remember is that \item doesn't treat the following text as an argument.  The hard part is telling where the text ends.  I also tried playing with \@itempenalty and \linepenalty with no effect.

Comment: If you are creating exam-like documents, maybe you want to look into using one of the existing exam classes? https://ctan.org/pkg/exam?lang=en https://ctan.org/pkg/mcexam and many more.

Answer (score 1):

Create an environment like

\newenvironment{questionanswer}
{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} \item}
{\end{minipage}}

in order to have all questionanswer envs grouped as a minipage.

Comment: What happens if the items take more than a page?

Comment: in this situation, that wont happen so I don’t really care.